# Fourier Transform of $ f(t) = e^{-kt}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to calculate the fourier transform of the following function:
$$
f(t) =\begin{cases} e^{-kt},& t \geq 0 \\
  0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

where $k > 0$ is a real number.

I can plot the equation fine but am unsure of where the limits should lie, I think I should be doing something like this:

$$
f(\omega) = \int_0^T e^{-t(k+j\omega)}dt\
$$
Would this be correct or am I going the wrong way about completing this?

Comment: Start with $2\pi\hat{f}(s):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-ist}dt=\int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-ist}dt=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-kt}e^{-ist}dt=...$, by definition of $f$.

Comment: this would give $\frac{1}{j\omega + K}$ I simply presumed this was wrong as none of the example questions I looked at resemble it.

Comment: The above gives $\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+is)t}dt$: can you integrate it?

Comment: Yes it gives $\frac{1}{j\omega + k}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the limits being T and 0 they had to be infinity and zero as the equation continued onto infinity asymptotic to the x axis.